# Can we implement Location features in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm wondering if we can implement LocationClient feature in a fragment; I exactly followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457535/android-google-maps-trying-to-use-locationclient-in-fragment), so my code is exactly this one, which very close to the official documentation excepting it's implemented in fragment instead of a FragmentActivity. But I finally have a doubt on it.

So I don't want to rewrite here the exact same code but just about the initialization, I have:

```
package .....;

import .....;
public class Fragment_init extends Fragment implements LocationListener, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // variables declarations
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("iconv");
    } 

    ... Other usual methods.......

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Log.v("2ndGuide", "Fragment_init: onStart");
        // Create a new global location parameters object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

        /*
         * Set the update interval
         */
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);

        // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
        mUpdatesRequested = false;

        // Open Shared Preferences
        mPrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(LocationUtils.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Get an editor
        mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        // Here I just store the Locationclient reference is a global structure
        site.setLocationClient(new LocationClient(getActivity(), this, this));

        site.getLocationClient().connect();
    }

    ... other methods. ...

    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mUpdatesRequested) {
            startPeriodicUpdates();
        }

    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
     * Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        getActivity(),
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }


    /**
     * Show a dialog returned by Google Play services for the
     * connection error code
     *
     * @param errorCode An error code returned from onConnectionFailed
     */
    private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {

        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                errorCode,
                getActivity(),
                LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {

            // Create a new DialogFragment in which to show the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();

            // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);

            // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), LocationUtils.APPTAG);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem here is that when I call connect(), none of the onConnected() nor onConnectionFailed() callbacks are called and I don't have any error but of course LocationClient.isConnected() returns false.

So I'd like to know if these callbacks are supposed to be called in this Fragment or if I really have to put in my main activity. In case, I'd be interested to know why the listeners don't work here.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes you can use them in a fragment

Comment: Where do you set the listener to be the fragment?

Comment: @323go, I think it's the problem, I suppose that new **LocationClient(getActivity(), this, this)** do that job but I guess that it doesn't forward the messages to the expected listeners. According to my tries, transfering this code to my activity and initializing Location client as LocationClient(this, this, this) immediately works. You pointed out the problem but I don't know how to specifiy the right parameters.

Comment: What you have should do the job -- I just don't see why you would store the LocationClient globally? It should be local to the Fragment, which is also the listener. Optionally, you could chain listeners or even use an event bus, if you want to share the LocationClient.

Comment: 323go I saved it globally to call getLastKnownLocation in an other fragment only for an initial connection to my server so maybe an additional listener is not necessary.